# Precession of the Magnetic Moment around B

Tags: magnetic-fields, precession

Equation 1.1.31 in this picture. How did the author reach to this solution from equation of motion? would anyone please explain it to me. I tried to derive it but no luck. [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Eq. B1.1.30 is obtained from the previous one by taking an additional derivative, which permits us to eliminate the cross-couplings between the $x-$ and $y-$ components. Considering the form of Eq. B1.1.30, the solution of the generic differential equation $\ddot{y}=-\omega^2y$ is found by substituting the general ansatz $y=\exp(\lambda t)$, as we are looking for solutions whose derivatives look similar to the solution itself, which motivates us to choose exponentials. This yields $\lambda=\pm i\omega$ and hence, $y=A'\cos(\omega t)+B'\sin(\omega t)$, which is formed by taking linear combinations of the complex exponentials to form real solutions.

Now, define
$$\mu_x(t) = A\cos(\omega t)+B\sin(\omega t),\qquad \mu_y(t) = C\cos(\omega t)+D\sin(\omega t).$$

From Eq. B1.1.29,
$$\dot{\mu_x(t)}=\omega\mu_y\implies -A\omega\sin(\omega t)+B\omega\cos(\omega t)=C\omega\cos(\omega t)+D\omega\sin(\omega t),$$
which gives us $A=-D$ and $B=C$. This particular result is obtained as the functional form must hold at all times. Further, $\sin(\omega t)$ and $\cos(\omega t)$ are orthogonal functions in the sense that the integral over the period $\frac{2\pi}{\omega}$, $\int_{t_0}^{t_0+2\pi/\omega} dt \sin(\omega t)\cos(\omega t)=0$ for any $t_0$.

Hence,
$$\mu_x(t) = A\cos(\omega t)+B\sin(\omega t),\qquad \mu_y(t) = B\cos(\omega t)-A\sin(\omega t).$$
Now, observe that $\mu_x(t=0)=A$ and $\mu_y(t=0)=B$. Therefore,
$$\mu_x(t) = \mu_x(t=0)\cos(\omega t)+\mu_y(t=0)\sin(\omega t),\qquad \mu_y(t) = \mu_y(t=0)\cos(\omega t)-\mu_x(t=0)\sin(\omega t).$$

The differential equation for the $z-$component is decoupled from the $x,y-$components. Further, $\dot{\mu_z(t)}=0$ for all times. Hence $\mu_z(t)$ is remains constant and equals its initial value $\mu_z(t=0)$.

Comment: thank you, that makes sense now :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a second order linear differential equation of the type

$\frac{d^2f}{ dx^2} + cf = 0 \tag 1$

where $c$ is a constant. Differential equations of this type have periodic solutions of the kind

$f(x) = cos(kx) + sin(kx) \tag 2$

Think about the first derivative

$\frac{df}{ dx} = kcos(kx) - ksin(kx)$

and then the second derivative

$\frac{d^2f}{ dx^2} = -k^2 sin(kx) -k^2cos(kx) = -k^2 [cos(kx) + sin(kx)] $

But the object inside the $[...]$ is the original function $f(x)$ so we can write
that the original function (2) is a solution of the differential equation (1) with $c = -k^2$.